# Enabling middle click for pointer stick buttons

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I'm running a freshly-installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Latitude D630 laptop. I generally use the pointer stick/eraser head to move the pointer around the screen, and the corresponding buttons to click (i.e., I don't use the touchpad or its buttons). I'm trying to use synclient to enable a virtual middle button click for the pointer stick-associated buttons, but have only seen how to do it for the touchpad-associated buttons.

Does anyone know how to do this? It seems like synclient only has control over the touchpad buttons (I only see TapButtonN for N=1,2,3)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with xinput! Specifically, I ran

- `xinput`: with no arguments to determine the device ID of my pointer stick, then ran
- `xinput list-props <device id of pointer stick>`: to determine the property name and corresponding ID that I wanted to change. In this case, it was Evdev Middle Button Emulation.
- `xinput set-prop <device id> <property id> 1`: to enable middle button emulation.

Then I added it to my global bashrc file to make the setting permanent. Voila!